# ordering data frame by column in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame `file` that contains biological data on gene expression in leukaemia patients.

> head (file)

```
     patient       expression Survival
   1     152          0.42900    Alive
   2      18          1.04060    Alive
   3     125          1.30100    Alive
   4      84          1.33410    Alive
   5     156          1.34644    Alive
   6     132          1.40710    Alive
```

I am trying to sort the first column `file$patient` in an ascending order. 
I have tried the following:
`file<- file[with(file, order(as.numeric(new$patient))), ]`
but I keep getting the following:

> head (file)

```
      patient       expression Survival
  77        1          1.33185     Dead
  75       10          1.28373     Dead
  143     100          2.24707     Dead
  161     101          2.50961     Dead
  139     102          2.23256     Dead
  71      103          1.16000     Dead
```

As you can clearly see, the rows in `file$patient` are clearly not ordered properly. Any insights as to why? and of course, how can I fix it. 
Thanks :)

Comment: `file$patient` seems to be `factor`, when you did `as.numeric` it just changed it to numeric levels, try `as.numeric(as.character(file$patient)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from comment, to make it answer as it answerd and solved the OP's question

`file$patient` seems to be `factor`, when you did `as.numeric` it just changed it to numeric levels, try `as.numeric(as.character(file$patient))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me unless I'm misunderstanding your problem? Since you reordered the data.frame the "rownames" will point to where they were in the original dataset. You can use

```
    rownames(file) <- NULL
```

to take care of this.

Edit: I see the error more clearly now. Also, you don't need to use `with` in your case. This should work:

```
file <- file[order(as.numeric(as.character(file$patient)), ]
```

Comment: Or `rownames(file) <- 1:nrow(file)`.

Comment: thx for the comment, but it did not change the ordering,  `file$patient` should give: `1 2 3 4 5 etc..` I keep getting `1 10 100 101 102 ...`which is not logical.

Comment: I just followed @Ananta's fix with `as.numeric(as.character(file$patient)` and it works !